# Can I use js package when building flutter mobile?

Tags: javascript, flutter, mobile, package

I am developing mobile and web with Flutter.

Currently when building with web I use js package to connect with javascript.

I get an error when I try to build on mobile here.

[image]

The js package seems to only work in web build. Is there support for both mobile and web?

Comment: You answered your own question, the package JS is supported for web only and probably will never support Android and iOS as mobile platform implements their methods using native language and not JavaScript which is dedicated to Flutter Web.

Comment: You *can* create a flutter_webview and execute JS within that widget.